# Scrolling fails on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: gnome, updates, scrolling, mouse-scroll, 22.04

I just upgraded from Ubuntu 20.04 to Ubuntu 22.04.
All scrolling was working fine on the v20.04 but now completely fails with  all applications after I upgraded to v22.04.
The OS was the only thing I updated.
I found this and tried but it failed.

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock extend-height false
```

I have also tried

```
$ gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad click-method 'default'
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad disable-while-typing true
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad edge-scrolling-enabled false
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad left-handed 'mouse'
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad middle-click-emulation false
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad natural-scroll true
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad send-events 'disabled'
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad speed 0.0
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad tap-and-drag true
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad tap-and-drag-lock false
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad tap-button-map 'default'
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad tap-to-click true
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad two-finger-scrolling-enabled true

$ gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.mouse
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.mouse accel-profile 'default'
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.mouse double-click 400
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.mouse drag-threshold 8
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.mouse left-handed false
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.mouse middle-click-emulation false
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.mouse natural-scroll true
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.mouse speed 0.0
```

Has anyone experienced this scroll failure and is there a fix?

Comment: Do you mean you can't scroll using touchpad/mouse? if yes, please [edit] your question with the output of `gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad` and `gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.mouse`

Comment: I  can't scroll using mouse, touchpad disabled.

Comment: You have in your mouse `natural-scroll true` which reverses the scroll direction ... are you aware of that? ... silly question but I needed to make sure  :)

Answer (score 0):

Natural scroll was the answer.

Comment: This answer is of little help to other users. Please expand a little on where to find that setting.

Comment: Quite sure he would mean that disablig natural-scroll solved the issue.
But the point that we miss here is: is ther a way to have _working_ natural scrolling on Ubuntu 22.04? I had the same problem: all ok with default scrolling. With natural scrolling it _first_ scroll in the default way, _then_ he start scrolling the _right_ direction